# How to show a LaTeX command in lstlisting?

Tags: latex, lstlisting

I code this in a .tex file.

```latex
\begin{lstlisting}
  % This is the syntax for inserting code.
  \begin{lstlisting}
  \end{lstlisting}
\end{lstlisting}
```

And this is what I expect:

```latex
  % This is the syntax for inserting code.
  \begin{lstlisting}
  \end{lstlisting}
```

Unfortunately, this is not feasible. What is the correct format?

Answer (score 0):

You can use another name for the `lstlisting`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstnewenvironment{mylisting}{}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{mylisting}
  % This is the syntax for inserting code.
  \begin{lstlisting}
  \end{lstlisting}
\end{mylisting}


\end{document}
```